# Salvar arquivo em PDF de uma determinada range da spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google, script

Minha primeira pergunta por aqui, um pouco trabalhosa, mas é que não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum.

Problema: preciso salvar no Google drive um arquivo em pdf de uma determinada spreadsheet. Este arquivo (pdf) tem de abranger uma determinada área, pois algumas colunas da planilha não podem ser mostradas. As linhas que não contém dados não devem ser impressas no pdf.

Minha ideia: Como algumas células contém formatacão condicional (vlookup) optei por esconder as colunas antes de printar o pdf. O problema é que não consigo fazer um script ou uma condicão pra só copiar as linhas que contém dados pro pdf.

Pensei em fazer uma outra planilha e mandar os dados selecionados pra ela e esta por sua vez gerar o pdf, porém as células que contém a formatacão condicional não geram os dados.

Até agora tenho isso e funciona. Só queria não imprimir no pdf as linhas em branco. Eu não posso alterar o formato da spreadsheet, ela tem de se adaptar ao conteúdo. Se alguém puder me dar uma luz.

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
  .getUi()
  .createMenu('ImprimePDF') 
  .addItem('ImprimePDF', 'printpdf')
  .addToUi();

}

//Imprime PDF
//Salva no Google Drive



 function printpdf() {

   //Apaga colunas que nao quero mostrar

   var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
   sheet.hideColumns(1, 4);
   sheet.hideColumns(17, 2);


   //Gera o PDF e salva no Google drive

  var spreadsheet_id = ('id');
  var spreadsheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet_id);
  var blob = spreadsheetFile.getAs('application/pdf'); 
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);

   //Mostra as colunas de novo que foram escondidas

   var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
   sheet.showColumns(1, 4);
   sheet.showColumns(17, 2);

}
```

Eu entendo um pouco de javascript (uso mais para funcões em sites associando com CSS), mas usando em Google Apps é a primeira vez. Já consultei vários lugares, fiz de novo um curso online de Javascript, já fiz o curso de Google Apps Script do Lynda, mas isso não entra na minha cabeça. Agradeço a ajuda.

Editando o post acima, eu consegui um script melhor. Porem ainda acho ele muito pesado. Demora 12 segundos para terminar a execucao. Mas parece que consegui resolver o problema dos dados que nao gostaria de mostrar no pdf. Se alguem tiver uma ideia melhor (desculpe nao ter acento, e que eu uso teclado estrangeiro no trabalho).

```
   function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
  .getUi()
  .createMenu('ImprimePDF') 
  .addItem('ImprimePDF', 'printpdf')
  .addToUi();

}

//Imprime PDF
//Salva no Google Drive



 function printpdf() {

   //Apaga colunas que nao quero mostrar

   var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
   sheet.hideColumns(1, 4);
   sheet.hideColumns(17, 2);

    //esconde as rows sem conteudo
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();

    for (var i=1; i <=numRows -1; i++){
      var row =values[i];var myValue = row[0];if (myValue == ""){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);

  }

 }

    //esconde as sheets com dados usados na planilha que quero gerar o pdf
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = source.getSheets()[1];
    sheet.hideSheet();

   //Gera o PDF e salva no Google drive

   var spreadsheet_id = ('id');
   var spreadsheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet_id);
   var blob = spreadsheetFile.getAs('application/pdf'); 
   DriveApp.createFile(blob);

   //Mostra as colunas de novo que foram escondidas

   var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
   sheet.showColumns(1, 4);
   sheet.showColumns(17, 2);

}
```

Se alguem tiver algo mais simples agradeceria muito.

Comment: Sabes qual é a parte do script que demora mais tempo? Consegues reproduzir este problema num jsFiddle?

Comment: A parte que mais demora e a do sheet.hiderows porque ele vai lendo linha por linha da spreadsheet. Cada linha demora em media 0.072 segundos e tenho uma panilha com 500 linhas. Nunc usei jsFiddle, na verdade nao conhecia. Vou me inscrever e depois coment novamente.

Comment: @Sergio, eu tentei acessar a spreadsheet no js.Fiddle atraves da url, mas ela nao abre (mesmo colocando no publico) entao nao consigo reproduzir nada nele. Uso o debug do editor da spreadsheet mesmo e o execution transcript. Como eu disse o loop "for" esta pesado, mas nao sei como mudar para obter o mesmo reultado. Desculpe minha ignorancia, estou aprendendo sozinha.

Comment: Existe uma forma de você ir direto para a última linha: `var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();` Pegando a última linha não precisa varrer toda a tabela.

Answer (score -1):

A função que mencionei anteriormente `get.LastRow()` pega a última linha de dados, portanto se houver linhas vazias no interior da planilha, não irá resolver sem varredura completa.
Mas se o problema for esconder as linhas e colunas após a faixa de dados, teste essa função:

```
function escondeVazio(aba){
  var aba = "comissao";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(aba);
  sheet.activate();
  var ultimalinhadados = sheet.getLastRow();
  var ultimacolunadados = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var ultimalinha = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var ultimacoluna = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var numerolinhas = ultimalinha - ultimalinhadados;
  var numerocolunas = ultimacoluna - ultimacolunadados;
  if (numerolinhas > 0){
    sheet.hideRows(ultimalinhadados + 1,numerolinhas);
  }
  if (numerocolunas > 0){
    sheet.hideColumns(ultimacolunadados + 1,numerocolunas);
  }
}
```